# Entity Framework TPC duplicated primary keys

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am aware that when using table per concrete type inheritance all derived classes share the same identity. What I would like to do is to have a seperate identity for **Guest** and **AccountOwner.**

After hours of googling I found two solutions. One is to use different seeds for derived classes, (I know how to implement this, but I dont like it), and the second one is to use **different identity increments.**

**Base class:**

```
public abstract class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

**Derived class:**

```
public class Guest : User
{
    //Other properties here
}
```

**Derived class:**

```
public class AccountOwner: User
{
    //Other properties here
}
```

If I were to use different identity increments, primary keys of **Guest** would look something like: 1, 3, 5, 6 and **AccountOwner** 2, 4, 6, 8.

The question now is,

**How do I implement different primary keys auto increments?**

**Have I missed something? Do you have a better solution?**

*I dont want to change my db structure.*

Comment: What exactly is the issue if you have Guest 1 and AccountOwner 1?

Comment: If i add one guest, that row will have 1 as pk. If i add another guest it will have 2. Now if I add one accountOwner IT will have 1 as pk, causing duplicates with the same pk as the first one

Comment: Yes, and why is that a problem?

Comment: If I have duplicated primary keys in the user table, I cant insert a user role for example because there are two users in the database with the same primary key. I know i have two seperate tables now, Guest and AccountOwner, but they still share the same baseclass, User, so the primary key will be duplicated. It's like you have only one user table and  you have users with the same primary key.

Comment: Heres a good explanation: 

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: But you don't have a user table, you have a Guest table and a AccountOwner table. As they share a Base abstract class, all you are getting is two table with similar columns.

Comment: Derived classes all use the same identity seed. Because the ID is in User baseclass, they all share the same pk. In the link above theres information about the problem with pks in TPC if you are interested in learning more. IF I add an accountOwner, the seed will go upp to 2, however, the seed for Guest will still be at 1, so when I insert a new guest, the pk will be 1 = duplicated pks. It doesn't matter if they are in different tables, they all share the baseclass and same identity

Comment: You say *Derived classes all use the same identity seed*, I'm interested why you believe this is the case. That may have been the case previously but in this simple situation, it's not the case.

Comment: Aha now I get it.. When I query an accountowner, I use: var user = Model.User.where(m => m.id == accountOwnerId); With this query I get duplicated pk exception. If I were to use Model.AccountOwners instead It would probably work. But why can't i query on Users? Thats one of the reasons i use TPC.. If i want to add a userrole for a user I wanna use the same function for both accountowners and guests..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't implement different auto increments.**

I have decided to go with Table per Hierarchy instead of Table per Hierarchy even tho I didn't want to change my structure.

Instead of three different tables I have now one, Accounts, and I'm using a Descriminator for the different types. Because I only have one table they all share the same auto increment.